# Find the inverse of $f(x)= 3x^2 - 3x -11$, where $x>2$

Tags: functions, inverse

> Find the inverse of $f(x)= 3x^2 - 3x -11$, where $x > 2$

The answer guide says the answer is $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{ \frac{x}{3}} +\frac{47}{12}$,
but i had $\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{x}{3} +\frac{47}{12}}$ instead.
How do i get the correct answer?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can you show us the steps that you took to get to your answer?

Comment: I believe your answer is correct. The term $+\frac{47}{12}$ should be inside the square root. You can check it yourself by graphing the three plots.

Comment: Note I also got that the $+ \frac{47}{12}$ term should be within the square root.

Comment: Also, writing an answer to be something like
$$
f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{ \frac{x}{3}} + \frac{47}{12}
$$
doesn't make much sense, because this would be just equal to
$$
f^{-1}(x) = \frac{53}{12} + \sqrt{ \frac{x}{3}}
$$
For these reasons, I believe that there is a typo in the answer key.

Comment: I think this was just a mistype. The typist omitted the braces after the *\sqrt.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the innverse of $f(x)$, you have to swap $x$ and $y$, obtaining:
$$x=f(y)=3y^2-3y-11=\left(\sqrt{3}y-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2-11-\frac{3}{4}$$
From here you solve for $y$, having:
$$x+11+\frac{3}{4}=3\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$
And so:
$$\sqrt{\frac{x}{3}+\frac{47}{12}}=y-\frac{1}{2} \leftrightarrow y = \sqrt{\frac{x}{3}+\frac{47}{12}}+\frac{1}{2}$$
Your answer is correct. There is certanly a typing error in the answer given.

Comment: @Anna: if this answer has been useful maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your help! I really appreciate it! It should be a typo in the answer guide.

Comment: @Anna: can you favourite my answer?